# How to debug "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error" in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just got run into the problem, many of my wordpress sites are showing me error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/sitename/public_html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 248

not one, many sites started showing this error, but not all sites, All of my these sites are on one server but only few are showing me this error, I haven't done anything to WordPress or code and haven't installed any new plugin, I also tried removing all plugins but nothing could helped me, can you please tell me what's the issue?

Comment: Error is pretty obvious.. Go to the file `wp-includes/default-constants.php` then on line 248, there is an `echo WP_Error` something.. wrap that in `print_r();`, and it should be fixed..

Comment: This is the content on line 248 in default content, please tell me solution, I dont know PHP too much, Thanks    "if ( !defined('COOKIEPATH') )
  define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('home') . '/' ) );

 /**"

Comment: Did you find a sollution for this problem @hamza-ahmad ?